# postgresql: can't select DB from windows with a restricted access setup

Tags: linux, windows, database, postgresql

I have a remote machine, that has to access a DB on my server.

I explicitly granted access with:

```
host    dbname dbuser  192.168.1.0/24    md5
```

and when testing from another linux machine with the command

```
psql -h hostname dbname dbuser
```

I can connect successfully.

However when some windows users try to connect to that database they have a dialog, where they
enter database type, (postgresql) username, password, hostname, port.

However there is no free text field to fill in the data base name.
They just have a pull down list and this pull down list is empty and the user receives an error message (free translation from another language, so not accurate to the letter)

```
Fatal error no pg_hba.conf entry for host hostname user username, database username.
```

So it seems this user interface tries to connect to a data base that has the **same name** as the user.
As this database doesn't exist and as I gave access only to one specific database the user is blocked connecting to the data base server and cannot enter the required data base name.

Is this a known problem?

How can it be solved?

Are there some special permissions to grant, that allow listing the existing databases on a server?

Comment: You'll likely need to launch the `psql -h hostname dbname dbuser` command at each user execution with `run as` or some method to give it that credential but make it transparent to the end-user on the Windows machine. Otherwise if the application support ODBC, perhaps you can install the drivers/components needed for psql and defined a connection with ODBC to the database/data source, and then have the application use the ODBC accordingly on the Windows platform. You just want the end user to be able to run command line as the SQL login credential without sharing the detail with them?

Comment: Problem is understood.
The customer used a rather 'stupid' client software for testing (some funny test client from oracle) Their real software can connect. 
Should I just delete this question?

Comment: @Pimp Juice IT Yes the idea was to give the persons on their windows machine read only access for data analysis. End they used some bad software to test whether the connection works. Their actual software is doing fine. But initially they didn't try their real software when the results with the test software failed.

Comment: Well, if you can get the specifics of that test software such as the name and specific version number and then the name and version number of the software that works, it might be worth you posting as a self-answer. I'm not sure what software you are using both for testing and production, but if it's common software or something a lot of people use, then putting those details in your own answer might help someone in the future. You had a problem and took time to write question, if you can help someone not feel as much pain as you did even by 10 minutes less than you, it is worth an answer to me

Comment: If the software it proprietary and custom and no other company/person will ever use it, then yes I would delete as it'll not help anyone. If you can disclose the names and versions of the software though and it can be used by anyone, you can help tell what the problem is for future readers, then you might help save someone's day or them to pull out less hair or less banging of their head against their desk, etc.

Comment: Good suggestion @pimp juice. Will post the software and version if I can get hold of it.
Will delete the question otherwise